# sql - SUM(CASE WHEN)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What's the difference between the two queries?

1st query:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (condition_1) 
           OR (condition_2) 
           OR (condition_3) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END)
```

2nd query:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (condition_1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN (condition_2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN (condition_3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: What do *you* think the difference is? Why don't you run them and find out? This seems like you could test this your self quite easily.

Comment: Are the conditions mutually exclusive, or can more than one be true at once?

Comment: I'd say, use alternative 1. (Listen to @rup, you may get a result bigger than the number of rows with alternative 2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two expression are not equivalent. The first expression adds one for every record that satisfies any of the 3 conditions. The second adds one for each record *and* condition that is met, so it can add up to 3 per records.

Unless the conditions are mutually exclusive, the results will be different.

Consider these conditions:

```
condition_1     id > 1
condition_2     id > 2
condition_3     id > 3
```

For this dataset:

```
id
---
1
2
4
```

The first expression would yield 2 (since 3 records out of 3 satisfy at least one of the conditions).

The second expression would yield 3 (since the third record satisfy two conditions, it will add 2 to the result).